# how logout from facebook using facebook-java-api in java web application?

Tags: facebook-java-api

I am using Facebook-java-api to integrate the Facebook app in java web app(Struts), i am able to post to the wall and able to get user information. now my question is how to logout from the Facebook using java also when i log in using java web app and just type Facebook URL the logged in user details are shown. how to avoid this? also how to get wall post of the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Java API does not provide this facility to do this. May be you have to look at some other way to accomplish this.